# Publishing React website on GitHub pages produces a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

So I've managed to publish my React app to GitHub pages, but the page shows up blank. There are no known errors that I can tell as of now. Here is a link to the master branch: https://github.com/SarahACollins/Portfolio/tree/master and to the website https://sarahacollins.github.io/Portfolio/ . I am building the site from the gh-pages branch; I'm not sure if I'm supposed to but if I build the website from the master branch, I receive a 404 error where the page is just not found. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[GitHub Pages screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3HAo.png)

Comment: This might help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/

Comment: Why did you just solve issue and not post answer to your own answer? Provide a way how did you solve your problem, please